# laravel sorting nearest coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, flutter, laravel-8

I have a MySQL table which contains a list of restaurants along with their `latitudes and longitudes`.
I want to send back the data sorted by nearest coordinate. I am calling the API passing users latitudes and longitudes  data and i want the user to get nearby restaurants.

p.s i am new to laravel and i  haven't developed the app, just maintaining the app.

```
<?php

namespace App\CentralLogics;

use App\Models\Restaurant;
use App\Models\OrderTransaction;

class RestaurantLogic
{
    public static function get_restaurants($zone_id, $filter, $limit = 10, $offset = 1, $type='all')
    {
        $paginator = Restaurant::
        withOpen()
        ->with(['discount'=>function($q){
            return $q->validate();
        }])->whereIn('zone_id', $zone_id)
        ->when($filter=='delivery', function($q){
            return $q->delivery();
        })
        ->when($filter=='take_away', function($q){
            return $q->takeaway();
        })
        ->Active()
        ->type($type)
        ->orderBy('open', 'desc')
        ->paginate($limit, ['*'], 'page', $offset);
        /*$paginator->count();*/
        return [
            'total_size' => $paginator->total(),
            'limit' => $limit,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'restaurants' => $paginator->items()
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the best way for laravel well.
But I want to give one approach to get near your location data from  some `latitudes and longitudes`data.

That solution is calculating sum `latitudes and longitudes` number. you can judge whether those data is near or not.

example here.

your location is

```
$yourLocation = [ // sum 200
                "userId" => 1,
                "locationName" => "london d.street",
                "latitudes" => 100,
                "longitudes" => 100,
        ];
```

and some data is

```
$someData = [
            [ // sum 210
                "locationId" => 1,
                "locationName" => "restaurantA",
                "latitudes" => 125,
                "longitudes" => 85,
            ],
            [ // 193
                "locationId" => 2,
                "locationName" => "restaurantB",
                "latitudes" => 100,
                "longitudes" => 93,
            ],
            [ // 233
                "locationId" => 3,
                "locationName" => "restaurantC",
                "latitudes" => 73,
                "longitudes" => 160,
            ]
            ];
```

then, if your sum location numbers is near target sum location numbers, that result will be near restaurant location.
like this:
If your sum location number is 200, sort restaurant list you expect is  restaurantB -> restaurantA -> restaurantC.

```
$yourLocationSumPosition = data_get($yourLocation,'latitudes') + data_get($yourLocation,'longitudes');
        // dd($yourLocationSumPosition); // 200
        $result = collect($someData)->map(function($item) use($yourLocationSumPosition){
            $sumPosition = data_get($item,'latitudes') + data_get($item,'longitudes');
            return collect($item)->merge(["diff" => abs($yourLocationSumPosition - $sumPosition)])->toArray();
        })->sortBy('diff')->toArray();

        dd($result);
```

result is

```
array:3 [
  1 => array:5 [
    "locationId" => 2
    "locationName" => "restaurantB"
    "latitudes" => 100
    "longitudes" => 93
    "diff" => 7
  ]
  0 => array:5 [
    "locationId" => 1
    "locationName" => "restaurantA"
    "latitudes" => 125
    "longitudes" => 85
    "diff" => 10
  ]
  2 => array:5 [
    "locationId" => 3
    "locationName" => "restaurantC"
    "latitudes" => 73
    "longitudes" => 160
    "diff" => 33
  ]
```

diff is managing sort condition.
laravel supplies some useful methods like `collect()` and `sortBy()` and so on...
you can check here.
https://readouble.com/laravel/8.x/ja/collections.html#method-sortby

try some.